# How to do select query in C# WCF service in Visual Studio and how to get the returned results?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, select, executenonquery, executereader

I'm currently trying to view the details of the table using a given id. I need to use select query to retrieve the data from the database.

I tried working with `ExecuteNonQuery`, but it crashes. After I searched, I found people saying not to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for select statement and to use `ExecuteReader` instead, but it doesn't work as well and exception pops up.

This is the code:

```
con.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select address from user where id=@x", con); 
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@x", id);   
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1); 

SqlDataReader s = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

if (s.HasRows) 
{
    while (s.Read()) 
    {
        add = s.ToString(); 
    } 
} 
else 
    add = "none"; 

con.Close(); 
return add;
```

This is the exception on `ExecuteReader` line:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=0x80131904
> Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
> StackTrace:

Comment: This is the code:  con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select address from user where id=@x", con);
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@x", id);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            SqlDataReader s=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (s.HasRows)
            {
                while (s.Read())
                {
                    add = s.ToString();
                }
            }
            else add = "none";

            con.Close();
            return add;

Comment: This is the exceptionon ExecuteReader line :  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=0x80131904 Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'. Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider StackTrace: <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: You should put both the code snippet, as well as the exception, **into** your original question by editing and updating it

Comment: Of course I tried to do so, but I get this annoying error : Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. I did what was instructed but it still would show up. So all I can do is add the code as a paragraph style

Comment: User is a reserved word (and a niladic function but who cares), you need to quote it in: [User]

Comment: The error log Indicates that `user` is a keyword and you may add this parenthesis [user] for user. Some code formats can also refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#overloads).